# mongoose schema setter overwrite function is not called

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to overwrite the setter of mongoose model because I want to create my own Date object, however checking the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/getters-setters.html) and I did following but the setter is still not called:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

function strToDate(dateStr){
    var dateStr = dateStr.split('/');
    console.log('parsed a date!');
    return new Date(dateStr[0],dateStr[1],dateStr[2],dateStr[3],dateStr[4], dataStr[5]);
}

var infoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    code: {type : String, require: true},
    valve: {type : Number, require: true},
    dataTime: {type: Date, require: true, set: strToDate}, 
    status: {type: Boolean, require: true, default: false },
    elapsedTime: 0
});


var dataLogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    boardId: {type: String, require: true, unique: true},
    logInfo:[infoSchema]
});



module.exports = mongoose.model('DataLog', dataLogSchema);
```

what is wrong? I'm using mongoose 4.0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you've got a typo in your `strToDate` function that's causing the function to throw a `ReferenceError` exception (which Mongoose apparently just eats). `dataStr[5]` should be `dateStr[5]` instead.

So just change the last line of that function to:

```
return new Date(dateStr[0],dateStr[1],dateStr[2],dateStr[3],dateStr[4],dateStr[5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this example with mongoose 4.0.6

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var InfoSchema = new Schema({
  dataTime: {type: Date, require: true, set: strToDate}
});

function strToDate(stringDate) {
  var sDate = stringDate.split('/');
  return new Date(sDate[0], sDate[1], sDate[2], sDate[3], sDate[4], sDate[5]);
}

var Info = mongoose.model('Info', InfoSchema);

var info = new Info();
info.dataTime = '1995/11/17/3/24/0';
console.log(info.dataTime);  //Sun Dec 17 1995 03:24:00 GMT-0400 (BOT)
```